# No installed ConfigArgs for the service "Apache", using Apache defaults

Tags: windows, apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I have installed Apache 2.4 on windows 7 server 32 bit.

When I restart the apache service, in the windows event Viewer below event is generated

```
[pid 2864:tid 400] (OS 2)The 
system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00435: No installed ConfigArgs for 
the service "Apache", using Apache defaults.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Apache is looking for a registry key

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\<service_name>\Parameters\ConfigArgs
```

Of type `REG_MULTI_SZ`, which can be empty. Manually creating the new key under your service of Parameters, then a new "Multi-String Variable" that is empty works.

Or if you need Wix to do it:

```
  <Component Id="CMP_RegistryEntries" Guid="{guid}" Directory="logs" KeyPath="yes">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\$(var.Apache_SVC_Name)\Parameters" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes">
      <RegistryValue Name="ConfigArgs" Action="write" Type="multiString">
        <MultiStringValue Name="ConfigArgs" Action="write" Type="multiString"></MultiStringValue>
      </RegistryValue>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Comment: Also answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59498302/2827127